# 'Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, group-by

I am trying to sort numbers column in dataframe but getting this error 'id' column has count of id's at specific stations. e.g. 2272, 2202, 1855, etc.

```
df.sort_values(by=['id'])
```

However, I am getting this error:

> 'Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy'
>   objects, try using the 'apply' method'

Answer (score 14):

You're trying to call a `DataFrame` method from `GroupBy` object.  If your goal is to sort within each group, you can simply pass multiple keys in `by`:

with `df` as a *dataframe* and not a groupby object ...

```
df.sort_values(by=['groupby_key1', 'groupby_key2', '...', 'id'])
```

If you want to sort within the group by, do as the error message suggests and use `apply` (with `df` as a *dataframe* and not a groupby object):

```
gb = df.groupby(['gropuby_key1', 'groupby_key2', '...'])
gb.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['id'])
```